# How to make the Diagram by using the tikzcd package?

Tags: diagrams

[image: diagram]

I would like to ask you that how can I make this two following diagrams by using the tikzcd package, I tired hardly but I always got a mistake. Any Help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: You can use also xy package

Comment: I got my answer, actually I tried it so much but directions confused me so much. Thank you so much for the recommendation. @JasperHabicht

Comment: the package is that hard? :) @Sebastiano

Comment: Ahahahahh it is not very hard....you can use LyX if you prefer. Also for me it is very hard :-))))

Comment: I see that :) I will try :) @Sebastiano

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX:SE!

What you try so far? Do you search for similar diagrams on site?

Your commutative diagrams are so elementary that you can find in package documentation :-). Anyway (since you are novice here), tray the following:

```
\documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
            & B \ar[dr] &   \\
A \ar[ur]  
  \ar[rd]   &           & D \\
            & C \ar[ur] &   \\
\end{tikzcd}

and\vspace{\baselineskip}

\begin{tikzcd}
A \ar[r]\ar[d]  & B \ar[r]\ar[d]    & C \ar[d]\\
D \ar[r]        & E \ar[r]          & F\\
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I read the package Documentation, and I searched the similar ones in site but could not find yet though. but at first stage, I am confused about this ''&'' issues. I am so glad that, I will keep learning it by using this codes sir. Thanks a lot @Zarko

Comment: @Sebastiano, thank you very much for edit! This night fall fresh snow, about 30cm. Nice idila outside ... however, it seems it also slow down internet since when I type text in answer spellchecker of SE doesn't show me error(s) :-(

Comment: @Dans0804, Your claims not hold. IN `tikz-cd` documentation see examples on pages 2, 4,  similarly and a bit more complex are on page 3 etc. Exactly the same image the  as you show in equation require a bit more search here.  Anyway, reading of package documentation (it is quite short) shows how to draw commutative diagrams with `tikz-cd` :-).

Comment: I keep reading, thank you very much, good evening from the second coldest city of Turkey where you can not evet stick your thumb out :) @Zarko

Comment: @Zarko Don't worry very kind friend.